# How to use custom Angular filter inside directive with D3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have a custom date/time filter I've built called `formatDateSimple`. I use this in my Angular templates like so:

```
{{givenDate | formatDateSimple}}
```

I've also built a custom directive using D3 (a scatterplot). I want to show the formatted date/time of each 'dot' in my scatterplot while hovering over them.

Below is the relevant code found within the link function of my directive:

```
function showTooltip(d) {
  var element = d3.selectAll('.transactions.x' + d.id);
  angular.element(element).popover({
    placement: 'auto top',
    container: '#vis',
    trigger: 'manual',
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return '<p>{{' + d.create_date + ' | formatDateSimple}}</p>'
    }
  });

  angular.element(element).popover('show');
```

This is the result in my tooltip:

```
{{2016-01-01T15:19:07.304Z | formatDateSimple}}
```

How can I correctly apply this filter?

Comment: Use $filter in the directive, JavaScript usage is described on every filter page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number, for your example it'd probably be `$filter('formatDateSimple')( d.create_date )`, don't forget to require $filter as a dependency.

Comment: @martinczerwi, that solved it! If you post this as an answer I'd love to give your credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$filter` in the directive, JavaScript usage is described on every filter page: [docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number).

For your example it'd probably be

```
$filter('formatDateSimple')( d.create_date )
```

Don't forget to require $filter as a dependency.